# [Autodesk Forge Viewer]How to implement 3D markup extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm looking for an official extension of 3D markup like "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui".
I'm newbie to Autodesk Forge API using viewer Version 7

I read this website, but this is not official one and too old. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card
This doesn't work out
this.viewer.loadExtension("Viewing.Extension.Markup3D")

Sadly, this extension set is deprecated.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.Markup3D

Does anyone know an official extension for 3D markup?

Answer (score 1):

The extension `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui` works in the last Viewer v7. This extension and the `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore`, which provides all the functionality, are not described in the official documentation. You can use [LMV Ninja](https://lmv.ninja.autodesk.com/) to try existing extensions.
This extension allows you to **draw** in the viewer in 3D.

The others links you provided help to create a **3D point** and some kind of **label** or **card** attached to the point.
The logic described in theses solutions can still work in the last version of the viewer with a bit of code adaptation, depending of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

"This extension and the Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore, which provides all the functionality, are not described in the official documentation." => 
Do you know if there is any possibility for Autodesk to stop developing Forge in a near future? The document is not maintained well.

Comment: But they are working. You can try to use Viewer v5 doc to get some details [Viewer v5 MarkupsCore](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/markupscore/)